# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined Webpack + AngularJS

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, require, commonjs

There's dozens and dozens of questions like this one, and none have helped because the root cause is always something I'm not doing. I'm making a bundle for the browser with webpack 4.26.1, and I keep getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined` when I open the webapp in the browser no matter what I do.

I'm not using `target: 'node'`.

I'm not requiring `webpack-node-externals`.

I'm not explicitly excluding anything from the bundle.

I'm not using `noParse`.

I even tried explicitly setting `target: 'web'` even though it's the default just to see if anything somehow changed.

This is the entirety of my `webpack.config.json`:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: './src/main/webapp/resources/app/template.core.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/main/webapp/resources/dist')
  }
};
```

This is my package.json

```
{
  (...)
  "main": "src/main/webapp/template.core.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.6.10",
    "angular-animate": "^1.6.10",
    "angular-route": "^1.6.10",
    "angular-sanitize": "^1.6.10",
    "angular-upload": "^1.0.13",
    "ui-select": "^0.19.8",
    "angular-ui-bootstrap": "^2.5.0",
    "moment": "2.22.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "npm": "^5.6.0",
    "webpack": "^4.26.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "jshint": "^2.9.6"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "jshint src/main/webapp --exclude src/main/webapp/resources/static,src/main/webapp/resources/dist",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  (...)
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For future reference, my issue was something as basic as having the wrong `<script>` includes in the html, because due to my webpack configurations, the bundles' filenames are different for development and production modes. I am now using `html-webpack-plugin` to generate the includes, with my template file being an empty file with just a comment so it outputs nothing but the script tags themselves. Here's how it looks in my `webpack.config.js`:

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {

  ...

  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'path/to/empty/template',
      filename: 'path/to/templated/output'
    })
  ],

  ...

};
```